# How to ignore any number of tabs, spaces in a line before the pattern anchor?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture a very broad range of sentences and words with a particular text formatting. I'm using JS regex, but Perl regex is also an option.

Example input:

```
(Name) + modifier1 modifier2 +
Some (ideas) sentences, words?! and ellipses…

(Name2) + modifier1 modifier4 modifier 16 +
Other words (... punctuation) sentences, words?! etc.
```

My "ultimate" ;) goal is to capture a string for further division into substrings with Name variable, modifier[] vector and dialogue "Some (ideas) sentences, words?! and ellipses…".

In the first line of input the () Brackets, +sign and words should be captured.
Then there's a line break after the +. In the second line I want to capture starting from (?<=\n) and including the first character [a-zA-Z()-,.;?!'’‘\u2026] and then capture any such characters but also '\s''~'':' [a-zA-Z()-~:,.;?!'’‘\u2026 ]{0,}. The second line capture ends after the second line break. '\u2026' Means an ellipsis.

My current 99% working regex:

```
(^\()[a-zA-Z1-9()\+ ]{2,}(?=\n)|(?<=\n)[a-zA-Z()\-,.;?!'’‘\u2026][a-zA-Z()\-~:,.;?!'’‘\u2026 ]{0,}(?=\n)
```

There are a few problems with the edge cases:

1. If the first line is preceded by '\t' tabs or '\s' spaces the (^() anchor excludes the whole line. It should ignore formatting and start from and including the '(' bracket.
2. If the document I'm reading from ends without a line break my last pattern won't match.

What would be the improvements I could make to deal with the edge cases? Is there a way to use ^ line anchor, but ignore the preceding tabs and spaces?

Comment: 1) Should the match span over the two lines? 2) Will the tex fed to the regular expression consist of only one pair of lines, or several pairs? 3) What do you mean by `^\()`? An empty pair of parentheses at the beginning of the line?

Comment: What's your expected output for the example above?

Comment: @Ava I'm looking to capture a string beginning with ( and ending with the second line break. Then I want to divide this string into substrings: the nameString `((?<=\()[A-Za-z]{2,15}(?=\)))`, modifiersString `((?<=\+)[A-Za-z1-9 ]{2,100}(?=\+))` and dialogue string `([a-zA-Z()\-~:,.;?!'’‘\u2026 ]{2,400}[.!?])`. The modifiersString will then be divided with '\s' delimiters into an array/vector of strings, each with a single modifier word.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin - 1) The match should be two lines long OR one line long if the (Name) header is missing. 2) The documents I'm working on are thousands of dialogues, each preceded by the (Name) header for the corresponding character OR without the header for the narrator 3) It should be like this `(^\()`, it's an anchor to '('

Comment: See, if my updated answer suits your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `((?:^|\n)\s*\((?<name>[^)]+)\)\s*\+\s*(?<modifiers>[^+]*)\s*\+\n)?\s*(?<head>[^(]*)\((?<ideas>[^)]*)\)\s*(?<tail>[^\n]*)` with `g` flag.

I have re-wriiten the regular expression making as few assumptions about the valid characters as possible, and also added some named captures.

https://regex101.com/r/3JgnhF/2.

Comment: I like this idea`(?:^|\n)`. I'll definitely use it in the future, thanks.
I managed to trim the input so I don't have to worry about leading `\s` and refined the match to `(^\()[a-zA-Z1-9?()\+ ]{2,}[\n][a-zA-Z()\-,.;?!'’‘\u2026][a-zA-Z()\-~:,.;?!'’‘\u2026 ]{0,}|(?<=\n)[a-zA-Z()\-,.;?!'’‘\u2026][a-zA-Z()\-~:,.;?!'’‘\u2026 ]{0,}`.